# How to catch Exception within a Task in Xamarin.iOS / Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

Xamarin.iOS 6.2.1, Xamarin Studio 4

I have this piece of code in `ViewDidAppear()`:

```
this.refreshTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.RefreshContent());

try
{
    this.refreshTask.Wait();
}
catch(AggregateException aggEx)
{
    aggEx.Handle(x => false);
}
```

The method `RefreshContent()` causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while accessing an array. I can see this if I run the method directly.
If I run it in the Task, as above, the application does not fail and I end up with an empty tableview. According to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx the code above should handle the exception.
However, the `AggregateException` is never triggered.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it a bug in Xamarin.iOS / Mono?

Comment: Could it be a threading issue? Will RefreshContent run on the main (UI) thread?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to include a try-catch inside the new task delegate? Like this:

```cs
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        try {
             this.RefreshContent()
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             // Handle the exception
        }
  });
```

Comment: This obviously works. But what's with Microsoft's example then?